# Can't Add Service Reference to a Project

Tags: wcf, net-tcp

I'm Trying to add a service reference to a project that has another references already made. I've Copied the App.Config and Web.configs used in those Projects and adapted them to the service that I want to add. I also copied and adapted the contract and I believe I've done it well.

**So my question is:** What do you think that I possibly did wrong or common mistakes while adding a service reference or equally helpful where and how can I troubleshoot the problem about the error of adding a service reference to a project with mex endpoint?

**The Error**
[image]

**Error Detailed**

[image]

**Aditional Info:**

The contract as only one operation("start").

The connection is being made through net.tcp.

The Service and the Object are diferent projects.

The Object has an App.Config and the Service a Web.Config

**UPDATE**

**Service Web.Config**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="traceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="C:\inetpub\SocketListener\logs\Traces.svclog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>


  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
  </system.web>


  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="SocketListener.SocketListener">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="SocketListener.ISocketListener">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://<IP>/SocketListener/SocketListener.svc" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="netTcpBindingConf" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:05:00" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000"
            maxBufferSize="20000000"
            maxConnections="20000000"
            maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000"
            portSharingEnabled="true"
            listenBacklog="20000000">

        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="200" maxConcurrentSessions="200" maxConcurrentInstances="200" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: show a service config

Answer (score 0):

try to add behaviorConfiguration to service:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="traceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="C:\inetpub\SocketListener\logs\Traces.svclog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>


  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
  </system.web>


  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="SocketListener.SocketListener" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBeh">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="SocketListener.ISocketListener">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://<IP>/SocketListener/SocketListener.svc" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="netTcpBindingConf" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:05:00" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000"
            maxBufferSize="20000000"
            maxConnections="20000000"
            maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000"
            portSharingEnabled="true"
            listenBacklog="20000000">

        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBeh">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="200" maxConcurrentSessions="200" maxConcurrentInstances="200" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Hello, i' ve added the behaviorConfiguration atribute but it didn't work, I getting the same error :/

Comment: serviceMetadata is requered for mex, you should keep working service when getting metedata also, and remove identity localhost if it is remote pc

Comment: At the moment I'm testing in the same machine so I need to keep the identity localhost. I think thats not the problem, could it be something else?

Comment: i think that you did not start service, because service, behaviorConfiguration for service and mex endpoint are enough for getting metadata. cmd -> netstat. does the list contain the service?

Comment: Hello again burning_LEGION, How can I see if the service is up and running thought the netstat? I don't know how to check the port of the service. (an addicional information is that the application in IIS was with http protocol, and should be with net.tcp, I've changed it but the error persists)

Answer (score 0):

This error was caused by miss configuration of the file *.svc and a miss configuration in IIS

**File Miss Configuration**

**Wrong**

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="Service" %>
```

**Correct**

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="<Namespace>.<Class used in the Service>" %>
```

**IIS MissConfiguration**

**Wrong**

in the application deployed in the IIS, 
in Advanced Settings,
I Had **http** in the **enabled protocols**

**Correct**

in the application deployed in the IIS, 
in Advanced Settings,
I changed to **net.tcp** in the **enabled protocols**